# Assign a value to select list (in a table) from a DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I'm having trouble assigning the selected value to a select list (that is in a table) from a DB.

The value is defaulting to the first option even when a value is passed to it and it definitely passing from my controller to the view.

I have also tried a different select list that passes the value correctly on my form, and that select list also doesn't work. So I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the table

Here is a screenshot of the value passing.
[image]

Select List

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListViewStatusOptions
{
    get
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Scheduled", Text = "Scheduled" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "OFR-Out for Revision", Text = "OFR-Out for Revision" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Tool Work Required", Text = "Tool Work Required" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Delayed", Text = "Delayed" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "In Press", Text = "In Press" },
        };
    }
}
```

Select List in Table

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <td>
       @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.ListViewStatus, item.ListViewStatusOptions, "Select", new { @id = @Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.Id )})
    </td>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the proper binding for a list of values will be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].ListViewStatus, new SelectList(Model[i].ListViewStatusOptions, "Value", "Text", Model[i].ListViewStatus))
}
```

you have to use for loop instead of for-each because mvc will not generate proper input names if foreach is used and the posted data will be not resolved by action methods

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a SelectList object new an array of SelectListItems.

Add this property to your method

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusOptions
{
    get { return new SelectList(ListViewStatusOptions, "Value", "Name"); }
}
```

"Value" is the name of the property that contains the id of each item.  You can have a list of any type of object not just SelectListItems.  This is why is may seem unnecessary to pass "Value",  Similarly, "Name" is the property that contains what to show the user.

Then change your razor code to

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <td>
       @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.ListViewStatus, item.StatusOptions, "Select", new { @id = @Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.Id )})
    </td>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and the explanation. I didn't get this code to work (I'm guessing I did something wrong) but it definitely put me on the right path and I now have it working I will post the code below. In your example it looked like it wasn't assigning the selected value

Answer (score 0):

My updated Razor Code.
As @ScottMacMaster explains,

> You need to use a SelectList object new an array of SelectListItems.
>   "Value" is the name of the property that contains the id of each item.
>   You can have a list of any type of object not just SelectListItems.
>   This is why is may seem unnecessary to pass "Value", Similarly, "Name"
>   is the property that contains what to show the user.

I was receiving an error for `Name` so i changed it to `Text`

I then assign `item.ListViewStatus` as the  object selected value

`@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.ListViewStatus, 
new SelectList(item.ListViewStatusOptions, "Value", "Text",item.ListViewStatus), "Select", 
new { @id = @Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.Id )})`

Comment: If you set the value of property `ListViewStatus` in your model, then that is the option that will be selected (so if you set `model.ListViewStatus="Delayed"` in your controller, then the 4th item will be selected. You do not need the 4th parameter in `SelectList()` above, and in fact you do not need to create a `SelectList` since its already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (your just doing it twice!). And read MajoB answer - you need a `for` loop otherwise this wont post back. And why create multiple instances of `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (one for each item)?